# Does uncooked oatmeal get less absorbed by the body?

Tags: nutrition, food, nutrition-information

When I properly prepare my oatmeal, that is by boiling and cooking it for roughly a minute, it really burdens my body to consume it. I feel fatigued an hour after eating it and my stomach feels heavy.

But, when I just drop the oatmeal in some water\milk and eat it right away I barely feel it. I also go hungry sooner compared to the alternative.

When I eat uncooked oatmeal, does it provide the same nutritional value to the body or does most of it just get disposed?

Comment: Care to explain the down vote?

Comment: Hi Leo, +1.  your question will be suited to this proposal:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition